# Inserting into database SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")

cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE order_history
                    (orderno int,
                    qty int,
                    price int,)
                    ''')

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO order_history VALUES (0001, 1, 10)")

cursor.commit()
```

When I run this, I get the following message

> cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE order_history
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

I can't seem to find the problem, any ideas?

Comment: Trailing coma is.

Comment: there's an extra comma here -> `price int,)`. Btw, prefer using `executemany` rather for the DML(INSERT Statement) as being more performant presumingly for large datasets. And use prepared statements which contains placeholders rather than explicit values to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma (,) before the closing bracket
.. price int)

I think that should do the trick.